# Access Javascript object values

Tags: javascript, object

I'm having a hard time getting the role(here Admin) in this Javascript Object construct.

I thought i would could access the value data.roles.data.role but that doesn't seem to be the case? Anybody knows what I'm doing wrong?

```
"data": {
           "gender": "male",
            "suffix": "Dr."   
            "roles": {
                "data": {              
                    "role": "Admin"
                }
            }
```

Comment: Missing comma after suffix.  Please use jsonlint.com or similar to check your structures.

Comment: suffix seems to be missing a comma though

Comment: @MrGeek: When editing, **do not** correct the code. Change indentation (if really necessary), but do not add the `}` when it isn't there.

Comment: Did you actually get any build errors, or debug if that json data you show us is correct? You are getting an enormous amount of response from at least 2 very capable people (myself excluded).

Answer (score 2):

Your object structure is not set up correctly, you have syntax errors:

```js
// You didn't have the entire structure wrapped with {}
var obj = { "data": {
                      "gender": "male",
                      "suffix": "Dr.",   // <-- missing the comma here
                      "roles": {
                                  "data": {              
                                           "role": "Admin"
                                          }
                               } // <-- Missing closing object brace
                    } 
          };
  
  console.log(obj.data.roles.data.role);
```

Comment: @MrGeek It should have been obvious to you that my code formatting was deliberate. It was done to more clearly show the nested object levels given that the OP made syntax errors with that. Think about editing someone else's answer carefully before you do.

Comment: sorry, I didn't see it until now, + I didn't down vote your answer, mine is also correct yet down voted too.

Comment: That's true, and you explained it correctly and I saw the error in my vote ;) It was an amusing question to watch from the sidelines

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have that *inside* an object, and you add the missing `,` and `}`:

```
var obj = {            // <== I added this { for the wrapper
  "data": {
    "gender": "male",
    "suffix": "Dr.",   // <== Comma was missing here
    "roles": {
      "data": {
        "role": "Admin"
      }
    }                  // === } was missing here
  }
};                     // <== I added this } for the wrapper
```

Then yes, you're correct, it's `data.roles.data.role` *on that object* (so probably with something before the first `data`); in the case of the above:

```
obj.data.roles.data.role
```

```js
var obj = {
  "data": {
    "gender": "male",
    "suffix": "Dr.",
    "roles": {
      "data": {
        "role": "Admin"
      }
    }
  }
};
console.log(obj.data.roles.data.role); // "Admin"
```

Comment: @Icepickle: I like to avoid the appearance of answering purely to get rep when answering **really** basic questions. CW posts don't generate rep for the poster.

Comment: And I thought this post should just be closed because of a typo in the json structure... I guess the gaining of negative rep is also foregone with community wikis

Comment: @Icepickle: I suppose that's true, but that's not why I do it. If that were my concern, I could just delete it if it were downvoted. I assumed the typo in the question was just that: A typo in *the question*, as opposed to their actual code.

Comment: There is also a missing closing brace on the nested object.

Comment: @ScottMarcus since he wrapped it in an object, he added both starting and ending braces

Comment: @ScottMarcus: Yes, you're right -- I noticed it (obviously, as I had to fix it) and forgot to mention it. Thanks! Fixed.

Comment: @Icepickle No, there was an additional missing closing object brace that TJ did put into his answer, but didn't mention.

Comment: @Icepickle: ...and that MrGeek added when editing the question. I've fixed that.

Comment: @ScottMarcus true, I only saw the editted version that TJ just reverted

Comment: Still, awfull lot of trouble for a question that should have been closed and hopefully deleted

Comment: @Icepickle: Well, at least half of it has been responding to your comments. **;-)** I like to be helpful, is all. The OP did at least make an attempt.

Comment: True, I am still watching in amazement how much traffic this kind of question is generating....